# "ul li a:link, a:visited" and "ul li a, visited" how they different?

Tags: css, css-selectors

1. `nav ul li a:link, a:visited`
2. `nav ul li a, visited`

At the first time, I use the method `1` to give a color for links in navigation bar. Then, when I create a link in `section`, it takes CSS settings that stored in `1`. I got method `2` from tutorial on youtube. It works.

But, I don't understand how those two different. I mean, when we use comma, should it take the same node level from the selector right before it? But why in method `1` it takes all links that available in the page. And, for method `2`, I don't understand why it works.

So, what makes those two different?

Comment: Protip: you do not use YouTube for HTML/CSS tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first selector is a combination of the selectors `nav ul li a:link` and `a:visited`. It matches any link in the list in the `nav` element, and any visited link anywhere in the page.

The second selector is a combination of the selectors `nav ul li a` and `visited`. It matches any anchor tag in the list in the `nav` element. The `visited` selector is useless as there are no `<visited>` elements. Whatever tutorial you got that from should be taken with a grain of salt.

What you actually want to use is probably `nav ul li a:link, nav ul li a:visited`. You need to use complete selectors, the `,` operator doesn't combine the content of the selectors.

Comment: Oh, that's the one I needed. So, it's my miss understanding from the beginning and both method that i used is wrong lmho.

Comment: It's not a matter of opinion - they are both wrong, period.

Answer (score 1):

### nav ul li a:link, a:visited

You are saying two things with this selector:

A.) `nav ul li a:link` selects any `<a>` that is **unvisited** that is a child of `<nav><ul><li>` but not necessarily an immediate child.

B.) `a:visited` selects any `<a>` that is **visited** anywhere on your webpage without regard to whether it is a child of anything at all.

### nav ul li a, visited

You are saying two things with this selector

A.) `nav ul li a` selects any `<a>` *without* regard to it being **visited** or **not** that is a child of `<nav><ul><li>` but not necessarily an immediate child.

B.) `visited` Does absolutely nothing. If it was valid, it would select any html element of type `<visited>` if it existed, but it is not a valid html element. Any effects you think you see from this are coming from the first selector `nav ul li a` because it encompasses every `<a>` contained in your `<nav>`

I hope this cleared things up a bit.